# How to loop through a 3D array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm trying to loop through a 3D array. Is this the correct way with using a regular for loop?

```
' declare variable
Dim cube(2, 2, 3) As Integer

' loop through pages
For i As Integer = 0 to cube.GetUpperBound(2)

  ' loop through rows
  For j As Integer = 0 to cube.GetUpperBound(0)

    ' loop through columns
    For k As Integer = 0 to cube.GetUpperBound(1)

      ' fill array
      cube(i, j, k) = i + 1

    Next k

  Next j

Next i
```

Comment: Yes, it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks. What if I did rows, columns, then pages? I'm just trying to find acceptable and conventional ways to do it. Isn't it cube(rowIndex, columnIndex, pageIndex)?

Comment: You have the `GetUpperBound`s in the wrong order. `i` needs to from from 0 to `cube.GetUpperBound(0)`, `j` goes to `cube.GetUpperBound(1)` and `k` to `cube.GetUpperBound(2)`

Comment: To answer the question in your comment, it is up to you which dimension of the array is the row, the column, and the page.

Comment: @Blackwood Thank you! And I actually just fixed the GetUpperBound order

Comment: @Blackwood Good catch, it would have been out-of-bounds as written. The order in which the loop should be nested depends on needs of the application.